# Remove Shortcuts from Menu Bar (Ubuntu 18.04 + gnome-session-flashback)

Tags: gnome

As shown below I have accidentally added 2 shortcuts in the menu area marked below. I would like to remove the same.

[image]

A better picture

[image]

Honestly I dont know **"How the menu bar is called"**. Could some one please point out where the related ***.desktop** files are stored so I can remove them.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the Gnome-session-flashback desktop environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "menu bar" is really GNOME Panel.

You have to do right mouse click with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> on each icon and select *Remove From Panel* option from drop-down menu.